# Defining a filename and calling the filename in various loops and functions

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

In short, I have written a code that opens up a file and does a number of modifications on it. However, I don't want to keep going through my script and renaming all the files when I want to open up a new file.

I'm thinking of setting a variable early on that defines the filename, i.e.

```
A=filename('png1.png')
B=filename('png2.png')
```

However, I don't quite know how to implement this. This is my current code:

```
import os

from os import path
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

#d=path.dirname(_file_) if "_file_" in locals() else os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:/Users/Sams PC/Desktop/Word_Cloud_Scripts/Dmitrys Papers/Word_Cloud_Dmitry')
Document=open('Dmitry_all_lower.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
text=Document.read()

heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("**png1.png**"))
print (heart_mask)
split= str('**png1.png**').rsplit('.')
extension=split[len(split)-1]
if extension == "png":
    image = Image.open("**png1.png**")
    image.convert("RGBA") # Convert this to RGBA if possible

    canvas = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255,255,255,255)) # Empty canvas colour (r,g,b,a)
    canvas.paste(image, mask=image) # Paste the image onto the canvas, using it's alpha channel as mask
    #canvas.thumbnail([width, height], Image.ANTIALIAS)
    canvas.save('**png2.png**')

    from wand.image import Image

    with Image(filename='**png2.png**') as img:
        img.format='jpeg'
        img.save(filename='**png1.jpg**')
    from PIL import Image
    heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("**png1.jpg**"))
else:
    print ('')


print (heart_mask)
stopwords=set(STOPWORDS)
stopwords.update(["will", "us","protein","residue", "interaction","residues","using","proteins","thus","fig"])
wc= WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords, background_color="white",max_words=1000, mask=heart_mask, contour_width=3, contour_color='black')
print ('Generating Word Cloud')

wc.generate(text)
wc.to_file("Dmitry3.png")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wc,interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
print ('Generation Done')
plt.show()
```

I've put the entire thing just to see what's going on, but I've bolded (put stars next to), the files I'm trying to modify in my idea. As you can see, I have multiple calls to my file 'png1.png', and I also have calls to save a modified version of that file to 'png2.png' and later a jpeg version of it 'png1.jpg'. I don't want to have to go through my script each time and change each one individually. I was hoping to define them earlier such as A=png1, B=png2, C=jpg1 so that I can replace the calls in my loops with simply A B and C, and if I do choose a new image to upload, I simply change 1 or 2 lines rather than 5 or 6. I.E.

```
heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("A"))
split= str('A').rsplit('.')
image = Image.open("A")
canvas.save('B')
... so on and so forth
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your task easier, perhaps you should establish a naming standard defining **which files are to be modified**, and **which ones are already processed**. Also, the images you are to process should have a dedicated directory for the purpose.

From what I understand in your code, PNG files are the ones getting processed, while the JPEG files are already done. You can use `os.listdir()` to traverse a list of files which have a .png extension, something similar to the one below:

```
for file in os.listdir( "/dedicated_image_dir" ):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        # Process your PNG images here
```

That way, you wouldn't even need to change your code just to accommodate new PNG images with different filenames.

Comment: The pngs are the files that will be processed, the jpegs don't need any processing. The issue is I already specify which images to be processed (that's what the split and extension line are for). The first modification is adding a white background to the image (for transparent pngs), and then I want to save this as a 2nd file. Then I call upon that 2nd file to be converted to a jpeg file, that I also want to save seperately. So in that loop I'm writing 2 different files. What I want is to find a way to define those files earlier, so I can modify what they should be called earlier in my script

Comment: Perhaps you can just create an input file, containing the filenames of the files you are to process, which you can edit prior to running the program. The program should then read the input file per run. That way, all you have to look at when determining the filenames of the images to process is the input file.

Comment: That still wouldn't resolve the issue with the output files. I'm thinking more of a method of simply defining what the input and output files should be earlier in the script, and simply putting in those definitions in the actual code for the modifications. That way I only need to modify them once (e.g. like when you have a GUI and input your files and specify your output files, and the code simply calls upon them through various places in the script)